# XJC superinterface and superclass only for all classes?

Tags: java, interface, wsdl, jaxb, xjc

I'm trying to automatically implement an interface in one java class generated from a xsd file.

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxb/vendorCustomizations.html#superinterface) looks as if it could do that, but it will only add `implements SomeInterface` to all classes, which is completly stupid. Am I missing something or can you only do this for all classes? Doesn't really make too much sence to let all generated classes implement the same interface. Can I use this feature for one class only?

Comment: To add insult to injury, this means that with the jaxb reference implementation, you can't properly define value elements because it will complain "@XmlValue is not allowed on a class that derives another class". That's a pretty huge restriction. So yeah I agree, completely stupid.