# Jaxb POJOs generation with Inheritance

Tags: java, jaxb, pojo, xml-binding

I want to generate the POJOs using the xml-binding with a different hierarchy that I have right now.
Now I have an xsd like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://manueldoncel.com" xmlns:tns="http://manueldoncel.com"  elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <!-- Base element that any element uses / extends  -->
    <complexType name="baseElement" abstract="true">
        <sequence>
            <element name="attributes" type="anyType"  minOccurs="0" />
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="id" type="string" />
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="Square">
        <complexContent><extension base="tns:baseElement" /></complexContent>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="Triangle">
        <complexContent><extension base="tns:baseElement" /></complexContent>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```

An a xjb like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="figures.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:globalBindings>
      <xjc:simple />
      <xjc:superClass name="org.manuel.metadata.Figure"/>     
    </jxb:globalBindings>
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

But, I would like to have a better hierarchy with this approach

```
public abstract class Figure {
    // some methods for all the figures
}

public abstract class ThreeSideFigure extends Figure {
.... // some methods for only the Three side Figures
}
```

So, the Triangle POJO generated from the XSD should extend from `ThreeSideFigure` rather than from `Figure`.

In this particular xsd I only put 2 figures, but I can have much more. I would like to be able to specify in the xjb that all the complexType should extends from Figure but only a few of them, should extends from ThreeSideFigure.

Do you know how the xjb should look like?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the [Metro JAXB RI](https://jaxb.java.net/) extensions will let you do that.

From the [2.2.7 documentation](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.7/docs/release-documentation.html#superclass):

> **3.1.3. Extending a Common Super Class**
>
> The `<xjc:superClass>` customization allows you to specify the fully
>   qualified name of the Java class that is to be used as the super class
>   of **all** the generated implementation classes. The `<xjc:superClass>`
>   customization can only occur within your `<jaxb:globalBindings>`
>   customization on the `<xs:schema>` element

That said, the answer to [XJC superinterface and superclass only for all classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926402) suggests that you may be able to do it with 3rd party extensions. There are some [details about plugins in the documentation](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.7/docs/release-documentation.html#jaxb-ri-extensions-develop-plugins).